# How to sync user's picture from AD to Sharepoint 2013

Tags: active-directory, picture, active-directory-import

I've followed this tutorial to try to sync user's picture from AD to SP 2013 but I've got issue in the first step: In dropdownlist for attribute I can't find 'thumbnailPhoto' to selected. It was disable.
[https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/46569/how-do-i-import-active-directory-photos-and-sync-them-with-my-site-collections#*=*](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/46569/how-do-i-import-active-directory-photos-and-sync-them-with-my-site-collections#_=_)

And there is some picture of my configuration
[image]

and [image]

here is the problem[image]

After create connection, When I click Start Profile Synchronize, nothing happen. The status still idle. I'v sure that in my AD there are over hundreds UserProfile. The number 17 mean, there are 17 User have accessed to My Site. I don't know why? . Could it be the cause of my problem?

[image]

There is one thing that I'm wonder. I can't start Profile Synchronization Service running because of I'm using "Sharepoint Active Directory Import".
[image]

Comment: Do you use Active Directory sync, or FIM? You may need to enter the name yourself

Comment: Yes, I do use Active Directory sync. But dropdown list for attribute still disable. I've updated some picture of my configuration. You can have a look

Comment: You need to fill in it manually in the text box called Attribute. And the click Add

Comment: I've tried it, but still not working. There is something I just found out. After create connection, when I start full sync. Nothing happen. THe status of sync process is still idle, it not change. Could it be the cause of my problem?

Comment: http://sharepointconnoisseur.blogspot.se/2013/08/suggestions-to-leverage-new-sharepoint.html

Comment: Were you able to populate the containers after created AD connection?

Comment: I've already populate it. and I select container User in AD which consist of over 100 users. But when I start sync, the status still Idle, it not change.

Comment: Do FIM service is running? Did you try restart it?

Comment: How to check if FIM service is running or not?

Comment: I just update some more info in Question. Pls have a look :)

Comment: FIM is not necessary for the AD-sync (that is new for 2013)

Comment: Robert Lindgren: So, How about my case? When I click full sync. NOthing happened? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Active Directory Import** is new synchronization method introduced in SharePoint 2013. It is highly efficient if only import is required even with AD only.

And that's true, you will not be able to start User Profile Synchronization Service after configuration synchronization method as **Active Directory Import**

You have to perform some step to create connection with a account that have **Replicate Directory Change Permission** on a Domain

> 1.On the domain controller, click Start, click Administrative Tools, and then click Active Directory Users and Computers.
>
> 2.In Active Directory Users and Computers, right-click the domain, and then click Delegate Control.
>
> 3.On the first page of the Delegation of Control Wizard, click Next.
>
> 4.On the Users or Groups page, click Add.
>
> 5.Type the name of the synchronization account, and then click OK.
>
> 6.Click Next.
>
> 7.On the Tasks to Delegate page, select Create a custom task to delegate, and then click Next.
>
> 8.On the Active Directory Object Type page, select This folder, existing objects in this folder, and creation of new objects in this
>   folder, and then click Next.
>
> 9.On the Permissions page, in the Permissions box, select Replicating Directory Changes (select Replicate Directory Changes on Windows
>   Server 2003), and then click Next.
>
> 10.Click Finish.

After performing this operation, you have to create a connection To **Active Directory Import** which you already did, so edit that file and select the container and click Ok there.

Then you have to map your AD  property to User Profile Property. Do remember you to write an Attribute instead of selecting it from dropdown. As dropdown will be disabled for **Active Directory Import** synchronization method.

In my case, I map mail to Work Email in user profile as shown in below screenshot.
[image]

If mapping already exist but **attribute** is null there then remove that mapping by clicking **Remove** button. Then add an attribute there and click **ADD**. Finally click ok.

**Note:** Don't forget to click **add** button after adding an attribute there.

Then run the full synchronization, check whatever property you had mapped are successfully imported to User profile.

But still, User Profile Synchronization service is not running. It all work without synchronization service running in case of **Active Directory Import** synchronization method. And even you will not b e start to start it.
That's I don't know the exact reason behind it!

But finally all things work perfectly after doing steps that I mentioned above.

**FYI:-** http://blogs.technet.com/b/meacoex/archive/2013/08/04/step-by-step-active-directory-import-for-sharepoint-2013.aspx

Comment: tks you so much. Now synchronizatino work OK. But picture still don't import :)

Comment: Another thing is. Not everyone in our company have Picture. So could it be the cause of my problem?

Comment: No, that's not a problem. It doesn't matter whether all user have pics or not. There is something else! Have you check your user profile properties "Picture" is mapped to thumbnailphoto attribute of Active directory

Comment: Yep, It already mapped with attribute thumbnailPhoto. 
I can see. Picture-----URL-----thumbnailPhoto. 
Then I run full sync
Then I run "Update-SPProfilePhotoStore -CreateThumbnailsForImportedPhotos 1 -MySiteHostLocation %MySiteURL%" but still don't work. I don't think that I'm missing any step.

Comment: I believe picture imports only work with external identity manager (FIM) and not AD Import option.