# sharepoint 2013 my site picture

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, mysite

hi if we upload users pictures in active directory does it appear in user my site picture? is there any way to do that because I upload one of user profiles picture in active directory it appear in lync and outlook but it didnot come in sharepoint  my site what should I do
best regards

Comment: You could manage this through using a SP list (a picture library).  Though I appreciate you might want to find a solution of managing it all through the AD pictures.

Answer (score 1):

You can import User Profile pictures from AD to SharePoint farm.

[reference](https://richardstk.com/2013/04/12/import-user-photos-from-active-directory-into-sharepoint-2013/)

Refer [For Good Answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/117895/how-to-sync-users-picture-from-ad-to-sharepoint-2013)