# Problems with import photo from AD to SP 2013

Tags: active-directory, import, spprofilephotostore, sharepoint-standard

I have imported user's profiles from AD to SP. I got all attributes that I need except AD photo (thumbnailPhoto). I did the same steps like [here](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/46569/how-do-i-import-active-directory-photos-and-sync-them-with-my-site-collections/), and the problem still exists. I double checked permissions of my account in "User Profile Service Application", also I checked DB permmissons of my account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint 2013 supports two types of profile synchronization:

1. The classic "Synchronization Service" with ForeFront Identity Manager.
2. The new Feature "AD Import".

`Picture-Import` is only possible with the `Sync-Service`.

`AD-Import` is not able to import pictures (see here: ["The AD import option does not support property mappings for complex types like pictures and special AD types."](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219646.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#begin))

You can check your configuration in the UserProfile Service by clicking on "Configure Synchronization Settings"

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did "AD Import" in sync in  UserProfile Service. Can I get some attributes by "AD Import" and get photos by another type of synchronization?

Comment: Sorry, this is not possible. You have to decide for one of them. But if you managed to get Sync-Service running, there is no big difference in SharePoint to configure the mappings. Please note that your existing Sync-Connection will get lost if you switch from AD-Import to Sync-Service. So document your changes!